# weather forecast web service by city name in silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, wcf, web-services

Does anyone know the web service for getting weather forecast information by passing city name as a parameter in Silverlight application?

In Yahoo weather web service I can pass 'woeid' only.

Is there a way to pass a city name directly and get the information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google has a weather service:

http://blog.programmableweb.com/2010/02/08/googles-secret-weather-api/

Comment: Ya thats a good one. But i couldn't access it from my silverlight application. It throws security exception.

Comment: Cross domain problem? You know you can still use google to find stuff, like here I found that using Google: http://www.wiredprairie.us/blog/index.php/archives/388